# Which tables would I need If I were to keep a log of password resets

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm really new to database design and I'd really apreciate if you could give some guidance on how to structure the tables that would be used to keep a log of password resets.
Searching a bit, I found this:

```
table user
-------------
id integer primary key auto_increment
username varchar
salt_passhash varchar
......

table tokenreset
---------------
id integer primary key auto_increment
user_id integer
when_requested timestamp
all_done boolean default false
```

But I'm still not sure whether only those two tables would be enough, let's say if I wanted to know :

- when was the password reset?
- when was the email send?
- how many times did a user request a password reset,etc

Shall I put all those fields in the `tokenreset` table ???

Any suggestions or ideas are more than welcome

Comment: Add a pass_audit (user, reqdate, oldval, newval ) table with a trigger to make an entry for each and every reset request.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

user

```
id | name | salt | password | email
```

password_reset_request

```
id | user_id | requested_on
```

password_reset_email

```
id | password_reset_request_id | email_log_id
```

password_reset_log

```
id | user_id | old_salt | old_password | reset_on
```

email_log

```
id | address_to | address_from | body
```

this would also allow you to implement things such as "same password can't be used within m days / n changes".

for comment: this could be implemented perhaps in a user defined function as

```
create function dbo.ValidatePassword
    ( @user_id int, @new_password varchar(100) )
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @now datetime = getdate()
    declare @i int

    -- check password not repeated within the last 90 days
    select @i = case when not exists(
                                 select 1 
                                 from password_reset_log
                                 where user_id = @user_id
                                 and datediff(d, reset_on, @now) > 90
                                 and old_password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', old_salt+@new_password)
                              )
                     then 1 else 0 end

    -- check the password has been changed 5 times or more since it was last used
    select @i = case when ( select count(1)
                            from password_reset_log
                            join (select user_id, MAX(reset_on) reset_on
                                  from password_reset_log
                                  where user_id = @user_id
                                  and old_password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', old_salt+@new_password)
                                  group by user_id
                            ) last_used 
                            on last_used.user_id = password_reset_log.user_id
                            and last_used.reset_on < password_reset_log.reset_on ) >= 5
                     then 1 else 0 end * @i

    return @i
end
```

Comment: and how would I implement such a query??

Comment: @TI In the example provided for the OP , there's a column `all_done` to determine whether the password has already been reset or not. How could I do that using your code?? Thanks

Comment: You could either add a status column to `password_reset_request` or you could add a foreign key in `password_reset_log` to `password_reset_request`

Comment: @TI Thanks. Just one more question please. As for the query: "when the email was sent?" Can I just assume that it was sent as the same time of the `password_reset_request.requested_on` ???

Answer (score 0):

ya two tables are fine

> table1
>   username
>    password
>   emailid
>   status
>
> table2
>   user_id
>   timestamp
>    hashid
>     ....

set status to one whenever user requests for password reset 
and you can count the number of rows with user id in table2 for number of request
and latest password reset query by timestamp